# Bug in derivative calculation GI type GAM

Tags: r, gam, mgcv, brms

I have many hierarchical GAMs fitted with the `brm()` function of the brms package. Some of my GAMs have a 'I type' structure :

```
y ~ 1 + s(year, by = site, bs = "tp", m = 2) + s(level, bs = "tp") + (1|r|transect),
        zi ~ 1 + s(year, by = site, bs = "tp", m = 2) + s(level, bs = "tp") +(1|r|transect)
```

Where year and level are continuous and site and level are categorical. I also have GAMs with the 'GI type' structure:

```
y ~ 1 + s(year,bs = "tp")+ s(year, by = site, bs="tp") + s(level, bs = "tp") + s(site, bs = "re") +(1|r|intertidal_transect),
        zi ~ 1 + s(year,bs = "tp")+ s(year, by = site, bs="tp") + s(level, bs = "tp") + s(site, bs = "re") +(1|r|intertidal_transect)
```

I want to calculate the derivative of the splines with 95% confidence intervals. To do so, I extracted posterior predictions of 1000 draws with:

```
msms <- conditional_smooths(model, spaghetti = T)
```

Extracting each draw as data a frame and making a data frame for each spline (each site and the global trend for the GS model) with something like that plus some data manipulation to have a draw per column and time in the first column:

```
f <- attributes(msms_count_4$mu_y: s(YEAR,by=SITE,m=1,bs="tp"))$spaghetti
f_SW <- filter(f, cond__ == "SITE_SW")
f_NW <- filter(f, cond__ == "SITE_NW")
```

I get these draws for the site-specific posterior prediction of the GI modes:

```
structure(list(year = c(1982, 1982.38383838384, 1982.76767676768, 
1983.15151515152, 1983.53535353535, 1983.91919191919, 1984.30303030303, 
1984.68686868687, 1985.07070707071, 1985.45454545455, 1985.83838383838, 
1986.22222222222, 1986.60606060606, 1986.9898989899, 1987.37373737374, 
1987.75757575758, 1988.14141414141, 1988.52525252525, 1988.90909090909, 
1989.29292929293, 1989.67676767677, 1990.06060606061, 1990.44444444444, 
1990.82828282828, 1991.21212121212, 1991.59595959596, 1991.9797979798, 
1992.36363636364, 1992.74747474747, 1993.13131313131, 1993.51515151515, 
1993.89898989899, 1994.28282828283, 1994.66666666667, 1995.05050505051, 
1995.43434343434, 1995.81818181818, 1996.20202020202, 1996.58585858586, 
1996.9696969697, 1997.35353535354, 1997.73737373737, 1998.12121212121, 
1998.50505050505, 1998.88888888889, 1999.27272727273, 1999.65656565657, 
2000.0404040404, 2000.42424242424, 2000.80808080808, 2001.19191919192, 
2001.57575757576, 2001.9595959596, 2002.34343434343, 2002.72727272727, 
2003.11111111111, 2003.49494949495, 2003.87878787879, 2004.26262626263, 
2004.64646464646, 2005.0303030303, 2005.41414141414, 2005.79797979798, 
2006.18181818182, 2006.56565656566, 2006.94949494949, 2007.33333333333, 
2007.71717171717, 2008.10101010101, 2008.48484848485, 2008.86868686869, 
2009.25252525253, 2009.63636363636, 2010.0202020202, 2010.40404040404, 
2010.78787878788, 2011.17171717172, 2011.55555555556, 2011.93939393939, 
2012.32323232323, 2012.70707070707, 2013.09090909091, 2013.47474747475, 
2013.85858585859, 2014.24242424242, 2014.62626262626, 2015.0101010101, 
2015.39393939394, 2015.77777777778, 2016.16161616162, 2016.54545454545, 
2016.92929292929, 2017.31313131313, 2017.69696969697, 2018.08080808081, 
2018.46464646465, 2018.84848484848, 2019.23232323232, 2019.61616161616, 
2020), `1` = c(0.0903901438415091, 0.102171563196727, 0.113952982551945, 
0.129014020398404, 0.149103806598073, 0.169193592797743, 0.191117621275084, 
0.213530781026471, 0.235097627348092, 0.252916514194966, 0.270735401041841, 
0.282408024975746, 0.289610639518398, 0.296813254061055, 0.2902458944272, 
0.283306373329117, 0.271128354990156, 0.249970055666827, 0.228811756343484, 
0.199417802015595, 0.167467954755259, 0.134773132363749, 0.0981051092726421, 
0.0614370861815133, 0.0261287888687987, -0.00807877805188554, 
-0.0422863449725695, -0.0680311864152342, -0.0933058764424676, 
-0.11409845247677, -0.1262715785247, -0.13844470457263, -0.140297494457864, 
-0.138464449999272, -0.135109382021439, -0.121708958816611, -0.108308535611782, 
-0.0914434142869732, -0.0714600646541677, -0.051476715021374, 
-0.031052940336138, -0.0105914149321213, 0.00825495044447179, 
0.0236018024283193, 0.0389486544121578, 0.0480260680379783, 0.0545492660364586, 
0.0600291597020738, 0.0566409665383091, 0.0532527733745464, 0.0456414389225931, 
0.0338069631824496, 0.0219724874423062, 0.00546466821953165, 
-0.0115929561188369, -0.0290745116954201, -0.0475966257658035, 
-0.0661187398361978, -0.0835478313887446, -0.100472451009983, 
-0.117150683727973, -0.130954402574742, -0.144758121421519, -0.157185149748638, 
-0.168082521942813, -0.178979894136988, -0.189877266331164, -0.200774638525346, 
-0.211688584495069, -0.222648937036328, -0.233609289577587, -0.24520100413079, 
-0.257121026930209, -0.269072787916266, -0.2815958362619, -0.294118884607533, 
-0.306130253196955, -0.317509546793416, -0.32888884038987, -0.337055347879519, 
-0.344619457974144, -0.350646697044373, -0.351721796147105, -0.352796895249835, 
-0.348754056481851, -0.34172575395595, -0.33449119001513, -0.319624953722208, 
-0.304758717429294, -0.287607586291897, -0.267314724743337, -0.247021863194777, 
-0.22567487363744, -0.20408985517491, -0.183252248402289, -0.165217435466824, 
-0.14718262253136, -0.133864392469005, -0.123622194715213, -0.113379996961422
), `2` = c(0.0281589447753082, 0.0360228847553418, 0.0438868247353754, 
0.0542065220785714, 0.0682917140452664, 0.0823769060119616, 0.0990794558874814, 
0.116479967872021, 0.133800230892946, 0.150765105646378, 0.167729980399809, 
0.18214865686438, 0.194715552755233, 0.207282448646093, 0.212271721394666, 
0.217056193517774, 0.218234485136086, 0.213230753031891, 0.208227020927692, 
0.195733806596412, 0.18091627019466, 0.164887189511126, 0.142396539324755, 
0.11990588913837, 0.0953530003646379, 0.06913068035352, 0.0429083603424022, 
0.0177391720305717, -0.00737150896464664, -0.0305577749798716, 
-0.050043242956679, -0.069528710933486, -0.0826863717986276, 
-0.0935841015524644, -0.103275101184265, -0.105001682010679, 
-0.106728262837092, -0.104648921431536, -0.0991442500172005, 
-0.0936395786028685, -0.0850102188719535, -0.076113028713903, 
-0.0675699556156343, -0.0597941361468887, -0.0520183166781475, 
-0.0477026543788269, -0.0447966857411216, -0.0425926203390234, 
-0.0463547324396034, -0.050116844540181, -0.0568723517603612, 
-0.0666212541001435, -0.0763701564399258, -0.0889238481726288, 
-0.101807515128021, -0.114445937172545, -0.12648239443585, -0.138518851699162, 
-0.147442691700809, -0.154929939120153, -0.161889368679005, -0.162690923198772, 
-0.163492477718539, -0.161194439863554, -0.155452410481069, -0.149710381098584, 
-0.143968351716099, -0.138226322333611, -0.131983419557772, -0.124338071280545, 
-0.116692723003317, -0.109620461991288, -0.102846206357157, -0.0962364745144016, 
-0.0925881709163024, -0.0889398673182031, -0.0871389645791802, 
-0.0876201452543117, -0.088101325929443, -0.0916514779767321, 
-0.0957770621563005, -0.100373400438514, -0.106486613051482, 
-0.112599825664444, -0.118637332497359, -0.124630677625246, -0.130575331305669, 
-0.134718401429927, -0.138861471554181, -0.141911821692888, -0.143459681851466, 
-0.145007542010045, -0.144765806376384, -0.144119968467057, -0.1432689308015, 
-0.141648394050079, -0.140027857298658, -0.138648923662264, -0.137427557274803, 
-0.136206190887341), `3` = c(-0.0539709293028476, -0.0537496486563462, 
-0.0535283680098447, -0.0522786240455355, -0.0494519029939236, 
-0.0466251819423118, -0.0391992632840588, -0.0305468919307008, 
-0.0204744488785012, -0.00411311687432633, 0.012248215129849, 
0.0323498353609559, 0.0551716652116509, 0.0779934950623591, 0.102357980235101, 
0.126764158794924, 0.149058589751514, 0.167732881959705, 0.186407174167906, 
0.195190131244194, 0.200903363624378, 0.20390162164128, 0.192420016387331, 
0.180938411133375, 0.160428244631795, 0.132609242834518, 0.10479024103724, 
0.0674567551735125, 0.0295946868616242, -0.00826605904612237, 
-0.0461242618690254, -0.0839824646919283, -0.114022138115743, 
-0.141269479611326, -0.16611936316185, -0.175146024275105, -0.184172685388359, 
-0.182546736516697, -0.171333438658595, -0.1601201408005, -0.134141380135618, 
-0.106897008373012, -0.0773884635227222, -0.0429742103157592, 
-0.00855995710881638, 0.0236217573947781, 0.0548939190933054, 
0.0849778245533993, 0.104961551986795, 0.124945279420179, 0.137628477017008, 
0.143011144777282, 0.148393812537556, 0.142732296530229, 0.135771464785536, 
0.127093455002492, 0.114200553670764, 0.101307652339029, 0.0895675478807852, 
0.0783595035179952, 0.0677226764786005, 0.0637500515454905, 0.0597774266123786, 
0.0598004232658113, 0.0642629994598431, 0.0687255756538748, 0.0731881518479065, 
0.0776507280419409, 0.0824611632887457, 0.0882456038833142, 0.0940300444778826, 
0.0973139227929918, 0.0992975087227821, 0.100846136701156, 0.0945655215540797, 
0.0882849064070032, 0.0774710464544904, 0.0610572958599553, 0.0446435452654299, 
0.0210351933610963, -0.00392214628882514, -0.0298341358608949, 
-0.0588222196265737, -0.0878103033922348, -0.115712683511179, 
-0.142981736502873, -0.170077615674274, -0.190766063494826, -0.211454511315367, 
-0.228409357364048, -0.240230500976425, -0.252051644588802, -0.257338274195062, 
-0.261149368380579, -0.263958087453723, -0.263007899855467, -0.262057712257211, 
-0.260596000222232, -0.258800685293739, -0.257005370365246)), row.names = c(NA, 
-100L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

And this is site-specific with the I model:

```
structure(list(year = c(1982, 1982.38383838384, 1982.76767676768, 
1983.15151515152, 1983.53535353535, 1983.91919191919, 1984.30303030303, 
1984.68686868687, 1985.07070707071, 1985.45454545455, 1985.83838383838, 
1986.22222222222, 1986.60606060606, 1986.9898989899, 1987.37373737374, 
1987.75757575758, 1988.14141414141, 1988.52525252525, 1988.90909090909, 
1989.29292929293, 1989.67676767677, 1990.06060606061, 1990.44444444444, 
1990.82828282828, 1991.21212121212, 1991.59595959596, 1991.9797979798, 
1992.36363636364, 1992.74747474747, 1993.13131313131, 1993.51515151515, 
1993.89898989899, 1994.28282828283, 1994.66666666667, 1995.05050505051, 
1995.43434343434, 1995.81818181818, 1996.20202020202, 1996.58585858586, 
1996.9696969697, 1997.35353535354, 1997.73737373737, 1998.12121212121, 
1998.50505050505, 1998.88888888889, 1999.27272727273, 1999.65656565657, 
2000.0404040404, 2000.42424242424, 2000.80808080808, 2001.19191919192, 
2001.57575757576, 2001.9595959596, 2002.34343434343, 2002.72727272727, 
2003.11111111111, 2003.49494949495, 2003.87878787879, 2004.26262626263, 
2004.64646464646, 2005.0303030303, 2005.41414141414, 2005.79797979798, 
2006.18181818182, 2006.56565656566, 2006.94949494949, 2007.33333333333, 
2007.71717171717, 2008.10101010101, 2008.48484848485, 2008.86868686869, 
2009.25252525253, 2009.63636363636, 2010.0202020202, 2010.40404040404, 
2010.78787878788, 2011.17171717172, 2011.55555555556, 2011.93939393939, 
2012.32323232323, 2012.70707070707, 2013.09090909091, 2013.47474747475, 
2013.85858585859, 2014.24242424242, 2014.62626262626, 2015.0101010101, 
2015.39393939394, 2015.77777777778, 2016.16161616162, 2016.54545454545, 
2016.92929292929, 2017.31313131313, 2017.69696969697, 2018.08080808081, 
2018.46464646465, 2018.84848484848, 2019.23232323232, 2019.61616161616, 
2020), `1` = c(-0.000282416573603693, -0.00271591733455456, -0.00516199276939573, 
-0.00763317487364931, -0.0101402837408418, -0.01269188461781, 
-0.0152950907197726, -0.0179470899003348, -0.0206404685928068, 
-0.0233625756144517, -0.0260886006877375, -0.0287915737231001, 
-0.031437529963855, -0.0339868139836993, -0.036399445019488, 
-0.0386347491982104, -0.0406519674557182, -0.0424151739981505, 
-0.0438952673011647, -0.0450652167105189, -0.045910951429386, 
-0.046424850317861, -0.0466048619383107, -0.0464628167632121, 
-0.0460130873752293, -0.0452772390725702, -0.0442831064189103, 
-0.0430590363960309, -0.0416347932713879, -0.0400404976146581, 
-0.0383029757461397, -0.0364440659241958, -0.0344842706185839, 
-0.032435721440793, -0.0303060775005323, -0.0281003022315046, 
-0.0258161655729922, -0.0234501743005459, -0.0209976917685226, 
-0.0184530137867315, -0.0158114123798943, -0.0130733195957459, 
-0.0102408732690352, -0.00732122639306472, -0.00432967830237086, 
-0.00128303518770019, 0.00179432791763776, 0.00487369521893103, 
0.00792538944203596, 0.0109170705038135, 0.0138160888004594, 
0.0165938183520947, 0.0192256568027686, 0.0216894482731145, 0.0239755222428691, 
0.0260785671039841, 0.0280010274528969, 0.0297588681317019, 0.0313703301860457, 
0.0328636713810393, 0.0342733156479352, 0.0356346133760946, 0.0369855582747931, 
0.0383644502188473, 0.0398039785036263, 0.0413308230683103, 0.0429713691168698, 
0.0447520018532761, 0.0466990099638965, 0.0488283941309507, 0.0511368816299008, 
0.0536177739273218, 0.0562486839040952, 0.0589968627764145, 0.0618266563341742, 
0.0646931096016521, 0.0675493345034615, 0.0703499950485326, 0.0730515359489744, 
0.0756122918458651, 0.0780021869538043, 0.0801958101461476, 0.0821751680228707, 
0.0839371812497683, 0.0854814166872423, 0.0868187774408077, 0.0879681955145901, 
0.088950472444891, 0.0897926924122859, 0.0905233522093606, 0.091169613195777, 
0.0917569952883759, 0.0923098773939077, 0.0928453286771147, 0.0933772651590566, 
0.0939160138803542, 0.0944641526576321, 0.0950230238032931, 0.0955907167807124, 
0.0961628514579845), `2` = c(-0.0893638592715282, -0.0875317466764431, 
-0.0856958539552433, -0.0838523737545187, -0.0819964065877801, 
-0.080121614455885, -0.0782214608016236, -0.0762886414261416, 
-0.0743154988298857, -0.072294645465396, -0.0702193278776524, 
-0.068083006882641, -0.0658811632845179, -0.0636109212944955, 
-0.0612704321011602, -0.0588620858596529, -0.0563894802637761, 
-0.0538590859979185, -0.0512814301960677, -0.0486677649179678, 
-0.0460328295545333, -0.0433930961160075, -0.0407654030739626, 
-0.0381674785115223, -0.035617065089155, -0.0331296702143186, 
-0.0307188530185536, -0.0283967465072349, -0.0261691074381822, 
-0.0240397453046267, -0.0220078796109846, -0.0200657802894222, 
-0.0182044146607224, -0.01640816753255, -0.0146579078505463, 
-0.0129331035313241, -0.0112095140996819, -0.00946231584134767, 
-0.00766748096428189, -0.00580172478182936, -0.00384289673934499, 
-0.00177445567984667, 0.000418299642416235, 0.002745604596645, 
0.00521044063815636, 0.0078144028256126, 0.0105519025043017, 
0.0134132303961086, 0.0163869166070966, 0.0194564825092788, 0.0226045179116448, 
0.0258131458624685, 0.0290640226493096, 0.0323394097864151, 0.0356250069233987, 
0.0389077235804468, 0.042177410412913, 0.0454290455924111, 0.0486585497860806, 
0.0518665074960122, 0.0550563743888019, 0.0582324619655299, 0.0614016542174202, 
0.0645713089873207, 0.0677479168036409, 0.0709370392352279, 0.0741441922891273, 
0.077374891972387, 0.080634624839924, 0.083925738085757, 0.0872446976679729, 
0.0905869194747165, 0.0939429757375555, 0.0973002396652585, 0.10064529044772, 
0.103962187748657, 0.107234489740723, 0.110446837286768, 0.113585113417898, 
0.116636018636522, 0.119591098484954, 0.122443847080729, 0.12519065289008, 
0.127833723088064, 0.13037627958946, 0.13282573317239, 0.135192461376869, 
0.137487432629253, 0.13972356747589, 0.141914210342991, 0.144071772628747, 
0.146207518903139, 0.148332146487061, 0.150452861424054, 0.152575364192648, 
0.154703722761441, 0.156838480820587, 0.158979625635534, 0.161125745294678, 
0.163274365617306), `3` = c(0.0731504541724651, 0.0656497283632369, 
0.0581727946194858, 0.0507434571968103, 0.0433860093175434, 0.0361253882507971, 
0.028985514791221, 0.0219822021524561, 0.015127504610437, 0.00842913405350016, 
0.00188472084093085, -0.00450979591794638, -0.0107626558146839, 
-0.016885498117432, -0.022889051724781, -0.0287796775341719, 
-0.0345623829106009, -0.0402340542407231, -0.0457801116431233, 
-0.0511830953713278, -0.0564087665136821, -0.0614145396640546, 
-0.0661521388573141, -0.0705591368971187, -0.0745707637001095, 
-0.078119434617396, -0.08113511178774, -0.0835500802414415, -0.0853078934650334, 
-0.0863556510074676, -0.0866544696675715, -0.0861866898203826, 
-0.0849395803451227, -0.0829291581710035, -0.080186801986411, 
-0.0767543113394985, -0.072701343191673, -0.0681028188942274, 
-0.0630456864047119, -0.0576281222096396, -0.051948432096607, 
-0.0461033962912715, -0.0401891661019579, -0.0342918951241707, 
-0.0284814954648778, -0.0228237871778161, -0.017358673878057, 
-0.0121111901579864, -0.00709633925879568, -0.00230028798482445, 
0.00229664856665519, 0.00672807767697247, 0.0110415290060614, 
0.0152856516752799, 0.0195119207479934, 0.0237726904150084, 0.0281130007957383, 
0.0325651349262517, 0.0371580086377128, 0.0418977759216758, 0.0467765761386907, 
0.0517774864620065, 0.0568555866974089, 0.0619599024250542, 0.0670254724478584, 
0.0719723546693145, 0.0767198722389097, 0.0811873483061336, 0.0852941659477631, 
0.0889660960106614, 0.0921408761030976, 0.0947595169893155, 0.0967865269064204, 
0.0982019339356302, 0.0989959634901983, 0.0991927480185298, 0.0988243466086145, 
0.0979434195877062, 0.0966262630430475, 0.0949532795258985, 0.0930230203521725, 
0.0909412626037069, 0.0888144800044607, 0.0867505119293326, 0.0848563383917516, 
0.0832253911771243, 0.0819415064348888, 0.0810803616636772, 0.0806882260354935, 
0.0808039343542264, 0.0814442566921647, 0.0825988423321457, 0.0842517372796568, 
0.0863593151278179, 0.0888660537100147, 0.0917104862462849, 0.0948183657654647, 
0.0981143443513779, 0.101531436833672, 0.105009007121677)), row.names = c(NA, 
-100L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I put one data frame at a time in this function to calculate the derivative with forward difference for draws of each spline and calculate the estimate and confidence interval of the derivative from the 1000 draws:

```
Deriv <- function(data){
mty1 <- data[,-1]

#calculate delta y 

mty2 <- mty1[-1,]
mty1 <- mty1[-nrow(data),]
m_delta_y <- mty2 - mty1

#calculate delta x
x1 <- data$year[-nrow(data)]
x2 <- data$year[-1]
m_delta_x <- x2-x1

#calculate derivative
mt_deriv <- as.data.frame(matrix(ncol = ncol(mty1), nrow = nrow(m_delta_y)))

for (i in c(1:ncol(m_delta_y))) {
mt_deriv[,i] <- m_delta_y[,i]/m_delta_x
}  
deriv <-  as.data.frame(matrix(nrow = nrow(mt_deriv), ncol = 5)) 
  names(deriv) <- c("year","y_deriv_estim","sd", "upper_CI", "lower_CI")
  deriv$year <- (x1 + m_delta_x/2)
  
for(i in c(1:nrow(deriv))) {
deriv$y_deriv_estim[i] <- mean(as.numeric(mt_deriv[i,]))
  deriv$sd[i] <- sd(as.numeric(mt_deriv[i,]))
  deriv$upper_CI[i] <- ci(as.numeric(mt_deriv[i,]))$CI_high
  deriv$lower_CI[i] <- ci(as.numeric(mt_deriv[i,]))$CI_low
}

return(deriv)   
}
```

It works super well for the site-specific trends of the I-type model and the global trend of the GI-type model, but the site-specific trend of the GI model is not very smooth, which is a big problem for me because I want to calculate the second derivative and each default in smoothness is a value close to zero.

What would be the cause of the difference in smoothness? What is the solution?
Thank you!

P.S. the required packages to run the derivative calculation function are `library(bayestestR)` and `library(tidyverse)`

Comment: Couple of comments (I'll take a closer look later), but your models seem to be missing a parametric `site` effect - the `by` smooths are centred about the intercept, so you need `site` as a parametric factor term to model the `site` means. If you want to estimate the second derivative of the splines - or combinations of them, you will need to use a higher order penalty than 2 on those splines. The model you fitted is trying to minimise the second derivative of each spline so you'll see these kinds of problems.

Comment: You might also need to increase the distance between the points over which you compute the derivative